# How to indicate in php 7.1 that the return type is the current child type?

Tags: php, php-7, type-hinting, php-7.1, late-static-binding

I have

```
abstract class A{
  public static function getSingle($where = []) {
    $classname = get_called_class();

    $record =     static::turnTheWhereIntoArecordFromDB($where);
    $model = new  $classname($record);
    return $model;
  }
}

class B extends A{

}


$x = B::getSingle();
```

`$x` has no type hinting... **I like type hinting, so I want type hinting for `B`, not for `A`**

How to enable type hinting directly for `$x`?

what I thought is something like

```
 public function getSingle($where = []) : ?get_called_class()
```

This obviously doesn't work

Is there something that does?

Comment: is there a reason why A is a problem as return value type hint? That means that A and all the children can get returned.

Comment: That seems a bit of a stretch... think `self` is as far as that magic would go. Interesting though. Do these possible classes extend a common parent? Implement a common interface?

Comment: @JoshuaK I want to have type hinting for class B.
@ficuscr `A` is basically a ORM for poor programmers. E.g. `save()` `refresh()` `delete()` etc but B will have some utility functions for more advanced sqls... currently, that is all. But everything is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you present, why do you need to have a factory method? You are creating a new instance from the constructor, why don't you just `$x = new B($record)`!

UPDATED ABOVE

---

```
abstract class A
{
    /**
     * @param array $where
     * @return static
     */
    public static function getSingle($where = [])
    {
        $classname = get_called_class();

        $model = new  $classname($record);
        return $model;
    }
}
```

`@return static` will type hinting its child class. Also I changed your function to static function, it is typical factory pattern.

Comment: a pity you cannot do `: ?static` no?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean.

Comment: `public static function getSingle($where = []) : ?static` is invalid

`public static function getSingle($where = []) : ?MyClass` is valid php 7.1 syntax and forces return type to be `MyClass` or `null` (thanks to the `?` null is allowed)

Comment: I mean phpdoc is ok. But it would be better if php would actually natively support declaring the return type to be `static`

Comment: You have your point. Maybe it will come true the other day. But if it is not for type hinting, I don't see `:self` different from `:static`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@method B getSingle` to the `B` class phpdoc.

```
/**
* Class B
* @method B getSingle
*/
class B extends A{

}
```

https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html

Comment: What I was starting to think also. @Toskan Is this simply for IDE sugar?

Comment: actually this breaks my IDE. E.g. doing `$b->getSingle();` now does not jump any more into the function but into the php doc. It is actually static, but it doesn't seem to work neither. `@method static B getSingle` doesn't seem to work correctly for me

Comment: @ficuscr proper code errors would be better but yes, IDE sugar is more important currently

Comment: Works in PhpStorm, at least the code completion works. But @bijiDango method seems to work better.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you specify PHP 7.1, but starting with PHP 8 (to be released on November 2020) **this will be possible with the addition of the `static` return type hint**.

[The RFC was approved unanimously, 54-0.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/static_return_type)

This means you'll be able to do:

```
class Foo

   public static function build(): static
   {
        return new static();
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {}
```

Additionally, no need to muck around with `$classname = get_called_class(); new $classname();`. You can simply do `new static()`, which is neater and has the same result.

And `Bar::build()` is type-hinted to indicate that it returns `Bar` and not `Foo` by virtue of late static binding.

Answer (score 0):

Let the abstract class implement an interface and type hint that interface. The child does not have to implement the interface explicitly.

```
abstract class A implements BarInterface
  {
    public function foo (): BarInterface
      {    
        return new static;
      }
  }
```

Comment: but `B` will have more functions obviously